# SSRS 2019 not show recently installed font type when export to pdf in WIndows Server 2019

Tags: reporting-services, windows-server-2019, ssrs-2019

Currently I have facing font type is not display correctly when export template/report to PDF in server.

I have SSRS 2019 installed in Windows Server 2019 and also install the new font in Server.

But when export the template/report in SSRS 2019 the new font is not been displayed correctly.
I also compare it by setup SSRS 2019 in Local in windows 10 and there is no issue when export same template/report to PDF.

anyone has any idea on this?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

delete the installed .ttf file in c->windows->fonts.. Right click on downloaded .ttf file ..select install for all users..restart the system
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0Jvs.png)

Comment: This worked for me on windows 2022 - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Fonts are embedded in the PDF file when the following conditions apply:

Font embedding privileges are granted by the font author. Installed fonts include a property that indicates whether the font author intends to allow embedding a font in a document. If the property value is EMBED_NOEMBEDDING, the font is not embedded in the PDF file. For more information, see "TTGetEmbeddingType" on msdn.microsoft.com.

The Font is TrueType.

Fonts are referenced by visible items in a report. If a font is referenced by an item that has the Hidden property set to True, the font is not needed to display rendered data and will not be included in the file. Fonts are embedded only when they are needed to display the rendered report data.

If all of these conditions are met for a font, the font is embedded in the PDF file. If one or more of these conditions is not met, the font is not embedded in the PDF file.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-builder/exporting-to-a-pdf-file-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15